# BASH: sed adding too much information when adding lines underneath a pattern and using an if statement

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a dynamic inventory file for Ansible. I would like to add some data underneath some patterns. Because of that I created an inventory template in which only these lines (group names) are added:

```
[all]
[apache]
[db]
```

I am trying to create a script that adds servernames and some other stuff, based on the servertype, under these group names:

```sh
_srvname="0003-customer-test-db10"
_envdir=$(pwd)
_srvtype="db"
        
cp "${_envdir}/inventory.bak" "${_envdir}/inventory" -f

echo "servername is " $_srvname 
echo "inventory is " "${_envdir}/inventory"
echo "servertype is " $_srvtype
echo "ip is " $_ip

sed -i "/[all]/ a $_srvname" "${_envdir}/inventory"

if [[ $_srvtype -eq "web" ]]; then
    sed -i "/[apache]/ a $_srvname http_host=$_srvname ansible_user=vagrant" "${_envdir}/inventory"

elif [[ $_srvtype -eq "db" ]]; then
    sed -i "/[db]/ a $_srvname http_host=$_srvname ansible_user=vagrant" "${_envdir}/inventory"
fi

cat "${_envdir}/inventory"
```

The output is not right:

```
servername is  0003-customer-test-db10
inventory is  /school/clouddeploy/scripts/inventory
servertype is  db
[all]
0003-customer-test-db10 http_host=0003-customer-test-db10 ansible_user=vagrant
0003-customer-test-db10
0003-customer-test-db10 http_host=0003-customer-test-db10 ansible_user=vagrant
[apache]
0003-customer-test-db10 http_host=0003-customer-test-db10 ansible_user=vagrant
0003-customer-test-db10
0003-customer-test-db10 http_host=0003-customer-test-db10 ansible_user=vagrant
[db]
```

First of all, it's been written underneath the wrong pattern. Second, why were so many lines added? What mistake(s) have I made?

Comment: why have you tagged ansible...  no ansible here...?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to create an Ansible inventory file. To create dynamic content for automated deployment using Ansible, you can use multiple languages. 
So, yes the code is BASH, but while it's creating an Ansible inventory file and I can imagine there are Ansible users out there, who have fixed an issue like this, I used the Ansible tag as well.

Comment: In a regular expression, `[` introduces a bracket expression; `[apache]` will match any of the single characters "a", "p", "c", "h", or "e" (the second "a" is redundant) anywhere on the line. You probably want something like `"/^\\[apache]\$/ ...`

Comment: This is very far from an [ansible dynamic inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html), It's a script which modifies a static ini file. It happens that it's final target is an ansible static inventory but that's the only relation to the tool. If you are trying to automate such things, you probably want to read the above link and maybe [developing an inventory plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html#inventory-plugins). If you stick to the present bash solution, please remove the `ansible` tag. Thanks.

Comment: Consider using python and outputting a yaml. `dynamic inventory file for Ansible` Why not actually use the dynamic inventory as intended with ansible? Just create a script that outputs the inventoyr.

Comment: Thank you all. Gordon's answer worked for me.
And: I learned that there are better ways to create ansible dynamic inventories!
I will definitely look into that.
I'm still new to this and i'm trying stuff and mess around.
Thanks for teaching me new insites!